# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Guid Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am checking if a Guid is empty when a form is being submitted.

```
public class NotAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if ((Guid) value == Guid.Empty)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult("You must add an image before saving!!!!");
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ImageContentGuid)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.ImageContentGuid, "You must upload an image before saving.")
```

The Hidden Guid gets generated from the Controller when the user uploads an image. The Guid *doesn't* get generated if no image was uploaded.

The logic works but the error message doesn't pop-up. Furthermore, the code carries on to execute and my program crashes with a NullReference since it was suppose to hault.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: show us where you generate guid

Comment: @Subby....where does the IsValid() method return to...in the controller.

Comment: And the code surrounding the call to Isvalid()

Comment: Hi Dmirity :) The Guid gets generated in the controller when the user uploads the image. And the "value" is successfully getting the respective Guid content.

Answer (score 0):

Guid.Empty is not the same thing as null.  Guid.Empty is filled with 0's.  A Guid is a value type, which means it cannot be null.  However, you are receiving an object, which CAN be null, converting a GUID to an object creates what's called a boxed value, making it a reference type.

So you need to verify that it's not null first, then compare to empty.

Comment: The problem doesn't lie within that.. I think. The problem i'm having is that the logic works but the program continues and doesn't *HAULT* the HTML. Instead, it carries on executing server-side code. Please check the Edit.